# Why is cos -x equal to cos x?

Tags: trigonometry

Can somebody explain to me graphically or intuitively why this is true? Because if we think in terms of the base of the triangle formed inside a unit circle it seems like it should not be negative.

Comment: "it seems like it should me negative": I don't follow you. Flipping the triangle upside-down doesn't make its base negative. Can you sketch that ?

Comment: Typo there, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to ask what $-x$ might mean itself in my opinion.  An angle of $-x$ can be viewed as a clockwise rotation whereas $x$ is anticlockwise.  Now in a unit circle you can record the $\cos$ of an angle as the horizontal distance on the $x$ axis and so intuitively the right triangle formed by rotating clockwise will have the same horizontal distance as one rotated anticlockwise.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

See we can write it as $\cos(0-x)$ so now use $\cos(a-b)=cos(a)cos(b)+sin(a)sin(b)$ to get the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry#/media/File:Webysther_20160305_-_Ciclo_trigonom%C3%A9trico.svg). For an angle of $-\theta$, you mirror the figure vertically: you see that this does not change $\cos(\theta)$, but it does change the sign of $\sin(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively $\cos(-\theta)$ measures the $x$-coordinate of a vector that measures $\theta$ degrees below the positive $x$-axis, so this is why we have $\cos(-\theta) = \cos\theta$.

Another way of seeing this is through the series representation of $\cos x$ given by

$$
\cos(-x) \;\; =\;\; 1 - \frac{(-x)^2}{2!} + \frac{(-x)^4}{4!} - \frac{(-x)^6}{6!} + \ldots \;\; =\;\; \cos x.
$$